# Does ui.overState is deprecated?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My HTML:

```
<ul id="tree">
    <li id="1">test1</li>
     <li id="2">test2</li>
     <li id="3">test3</li>
     <li id="4">test4</li>
</ul>
```

and JQuery :

```
 $("#tree li").draggable().droppable({

                    element: '#tree',
                    tolerance: 'pointer',
                    aroundTop: '25%',
                    aroundBottom: '25%',
                    aroundLeft: 0,
                    aroundRight: 0,
                    drop: function(event,ui) {
                         alert(ui.overState);//desire result is 'top' ,'bottom' ,center
                        }
                });
```

But I get a value of alert is `undefined` .I search and fail to solve a problem but according [this](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4737) document it is exist.
So why I got to fail to catch `ui.overState`.If it is deprecated suggest me its alternative.  Thanks.

Sample Fiddle: [ui.overState](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/U5WhB/2/)

Comment: have you include jquery ui ?

Comment: yap see my fiddle and try your self.

Answer (score 0):

try **[ui.position](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop)**

```
 $("#tree li").draggable().droppable({

                    element: '#tree',
                    tolerance: 'pointer',
                    aroundTop: '25%',
                    aroundBottom: '25%',
                    aroundLeft: 0,
                    aroundRight: 0,
                    drop: function(event,ui) {
         alert("top="+ui.position.top+"  left="+ui.position.left);//desire result is 'top' ,'bottom' ,center
                        console.log(ui.position);// see in console
                        }
                });
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U5WhB/10/)**